# Why does the type-checker allow this code?

Tags: typescript

Is it OK that such code passes type-checking?

```
function infiniteLoop(): never {
    while (true) {
    }
}
let x = infiniteLoop();
```

How can `x` exist and thus to inhabit `never` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`never` is a type. Any variable can have this type (because any variable can have any type). So when you say `let x = infiniteLoop()`, Typescript infers that `x` has type `never`. It is perfectly fine.

But, and that's where it's useful, it prevents you from using `x` later on. That's what would be the real semantical error.

See [this explanation](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/never-type.html) for some more examples.

More generally, you cannot expect from a type-system that it will statically handle infinite loop detection. That's because it is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for a type-system.

Typescript approach allows to statically pinpoint unwanted behaviour when you explicitly give the `never` type hints. Specifically, it prevents you from using the result of a computation that you explicitly declare to be non-ending (or returning from a computation that you declare non-ending).

Comment: "it prevents you from using x later on". What do you mean? I tried even `console.log(x)` and did not get any error.

Comment: yeah right, `console.log` is probably not the best example because it accepts any type so there is no type-checking. What I mean is that type `never` will never type-check against any other type - when you use it in a way where there is a check. That's the best possible given the Typescript typing mechanism. Not bulletproof as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer to own question. `never` [seems to be "bottom" type](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-never-type-in-typescript). But "bottom" is a sub-type of any other types:

```
function f() : never
{
    return (1 as never); // but is not true for "as void".
}
```

> bottom is an inhabitant of every type (though with some caveats
>   concerning types of unboxed kind), bottoms can be used wherever a
>   value of that type would be ([here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom)).

So, the `infiniteLoop()` can return `never` and any type includes `never` as its sub-type and it can be declared even:

```js
let x:never;
```

And since it's a sub-type of any other type, value of them can be "casted" (with `as`) to the `never`. But super-set cannot be assigned to it's sub-set, for example `Triangle` type to `never` - this is the reason why we get an error here:

```js
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle | Triangle;

function assertNever(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Unexpected object: " + x);
}
function area(s: Shape) {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.height * s.width;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius ** 2;
        default: return assertNever(s); // error here if there are missing cases
    }
}
```